# android in app purchase with limited period validity

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am developing app in which user can watch videos online. In this some videos are free and some other are paid one. So I want to implement in app feature which should allow user to buy paid video for limited period say 48 hours and once user purchased  the video , he should watch the video within 48 hours. After 48 hours the in app purchased video should automatically expire.

Please give your suggestions to implement this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use consumable purchases. Have a look at the link below

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Consume

Have a look at consuming a purchase.